# select how many time a value is repeated inside multi-value columns

Tags: mysql

Consider this table

```
student_name  grade
steve         a, b,d
mike          c,d,b
bob           a,d
```

I would like to write a query to pull the number of grade I do have
out put

```
a    2
b    2
c    1
d    3
```

I've tried:

```
select s1.grade, count(s1.grade) from student s1, student s2
where s1.grade = s2.grade
group by s1.grade
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty, but this is one reason why you don't want to violate first normal form and have multi-valued columns...

```
select 'a' as grade, count(*) as occurrences
from student
where grade like '%a%'

union all

select 'b' as grade, count(*) as occurrences
from student
where grade like '%b%'

union all

select 'c' as grade, count(*) as occurrences
from student
where grade like '%c%'

union all

select 'd' as grade, count(*) as occurrences
from student
where grade like '%d%'
```

[See it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/639d0/1).

Alternately, if you have  `grades` table like the one proposed by Chris K, you could do something like the following:

```
select g.grade, count(s.student_name) as occurances
from 
  grades g
  left join student s
    on concat(',', s.grade, ',') like concat('%,', g.grade, ',%')
group by g.grade
```

[See it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd069d/13).

Comment: is there's a way to do that directly without doing so many unions? because I do have more than that, a+, b+, c+, d+
and that will be a very heavy query. thanks a lot thought!!!!

Comment: @Michael That won't work if his data contains spaces like in the example

Comment: replace `concat(',', s.grade, ',')` with `concat(',', replace(s.grade, ' ', ''), ',')` to deal with the spaces

Answer (score 2):

Or if you have a table (called `grades`) containing a list of possible grades:

```
grade
-----
a
b
c
d
e
```

Then the following statement would also work:

```
select g.grade as [Grade], (select count(1) from student where grade like '%'+g.grade+'%') as [Count] from grades g order by g.grade asc
```

This would maybe be more flexible in terms of adding other potential grades to the count.

But as said above... avoid normalisation at your peril...

Comment: If you also have grades like `a+` and `a-` then you will have to do some tidying up of the data to get the true values: searching for like `%a%` will include the count of `a+` and `a-` - so you'll need to subtract these from the count returned for `a` - there is no way around this given the way your data is stored.